# Change soft keyboarb type from webview

Tags: android

Are there any ways to change keyboard type(as it shown in screenshots) programmatically in the webview?

[image: from this type] [image: to this type]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the input type in webpage.
If the input type in numeric in webpage, then the keyboard in android automatically changes.

Comment: If I put type="number" to the input element in html, then I will get ONLY digits in keyboard. But I need keyboard type just like in screenshot.

Comment: I don't get numeric keyboard on `type=number` html field. Is there anything else necessary to activate this?